# Feed Forward ANN: calculating delta node from previous layer delta

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement a feed forward neural network in CUDA.
So far, I've used [Jeff Heaton's YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/HeatonResearch/videos) as a guide to infer the algorithms and implement them.
I'm not clear on one thing:

Heaton in his [Gradient Calculation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1-FiWjThs8) video, explains how to get the node delta δ[i] for output neurons. 
Then I have to reuse it as δ[k] in my previous (hidden layer) in order to calculate δ[i].

However, there is no mention of what happens when **I have more than one node delta**, or more than one outgoing weights for layer *i* to layer *k*. Similarly its confusing on how I calculate the gradient for a specific weight; do I use a node delta, or a layer's delta?

For example, what happens if my output layer has 2 neurons? Do I sum the δ[k] for all nodes in layer *k*?

The formula provided by Heaton:

```
f'( Sum (weight[i] * input[i] ) ) * Σ w[ki]  * δ[k]
```

Appears to suggest that δ[k] is representative of the previous layer (and not just the output node) as shown in the video @ 9:25'.

In fact, two of the comments in that YouTube video also ask the same thing, but no satisfactory reply is given.

As far as I understand, δ[k] represents the error from the previous/following layer *k* to which layer *i* connects to, and not the **node** to which current node in layer *i* connects to?

**EDIT**

I've read a few papers and tutorials/lessons online, but the one that seems to somewhat answer my question, can be [found here](http://arduinobasics.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/neural-network-part-5-back-propagation.html).
In specific, the formula the blog's author uses, is the same as the one used by Heaton, but he explains:

```
HLN = Hidden Layer Neuron, 
LLN = Last Layer Neuron,
aO=actualOUTPUT,
dE=deltaError


HLN.dE = (HLN.aO) x (1-HLN.aO) x (Sum of   [LLN.dE   x   LLN to HLN connection weight])
```

This seems to imply that the formula actually is:

```
Si = Σ (w[ji] * a[j])
δ[i] = f'( Si ) * Σ( w[ki]  * δ[k] )
```

In words:

> The Sum of the previous activation outputs multiplied by their edges
>   (weights), is put through the sigmoid derivative.
>
> Then for each out-going weight *w[ki]* is multiplied by the respective
>   *δ[k]* (e.g., the *w[ki]* * *δ[κ]*).  Those values are summed, and multiplied with the result of the sigmoid derivative.

I'd still like to hear from someone who has implemented a feed-forward neural network, if that is what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. Probably the most easy way to formalize the update is:

[image]

with f'(x) being the derivative of the activation function, x_i the output of the sending unit i and x_j from the receiving unit j. So in words, you sum the deltas over all connections that the current unit has towards the **previously** visited layer (hence, *back*propagation).

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Why is it f'(xj) and not f'(zj) with zj being the weighted sum of the incoming inputs to node j?

Comment: @Kie The formalization above (I wrote it 5 years ago) is definitely counterintuitive to today's variable naming standards but it is supposed to mean exactly what you said, namely "output (!) of the receiving unit x_j" = z_j = sum w_ij * x_i.